# Ant-Design tags not working properly with my Javascript logic

Tags: javascript, reactjs, antd

I am using Ant-design in my React project so I am using  tags given by them in my own project
[Tags](https://ant.design/components/tag/)

So here is my code

Parent component

```
export default function FormSection() {
  const tagsData = ['1','2 ','3']
  const tagsData1 = ['a','b ','c']
  const getValueofTag = value => {
     console.log(value)
  }

  return (
    <div className="form-section">
      <form>
     
        <div className="selectable-tags-mortgage">
          {tagsData.map(tag => (
            <CheckableAntTag tag={tag} getValueofTag={getValueofTag} />
          ))}
        </div>

        <div className="selectable-tags-holders">
          {tagsData1.map(tag => (
            <CheckableAntTag tag={tag} getValueofTag={getValueofTag} />
          ))}
        </div>
       
      </form>
    </div>
  )
}
```

CheckableAntTag is a child component as I want to make this component reusable so I made this is a separate component

Child Component

import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react'
import { Tag } from 'antd'
import PropTypes from 'prop-types'

```
export default function CheckableAntTag({ tag, getValueofTag }) {
  const [selectedTags, setSelectedTags] = useState('')
  const { CheckableTag } = Tag
  const handleChange1 = (tag, checked) => {
    const nextSelectedTags = checked ? [tag] : selectedTags.filter(t => t !== tag)
    setSelectedTags(nextSelectedTags)
    getValueofTag(nextSelectedTags)
  }
  return (
    <CheckableTag
      style={{
        backgroundColor: selectedTags.indexOf(tag) > -1 ? 'red' : 'orange'
      }}
      key={tag}
      checked={selectedTags.indexOf(tag) > -1 ? true : false}
      onChange={checked => handleChange1(tag, checked)}>
      {tag}
    </CheckableTag>
  )
}

CheckableAntTag.propTypes = {
  tag: PropTypes.object,
  getValueofTag: PropTypes.func
}
```

With this logic, the issue I am facing is when I click on the tag the value gets set in the state and the background colour changes and then when I click on other tags the value does get set in the state(replacing the previous) but the background colour still remains the same.

Please refer to the screenshot below to get more clear what issue I am facing

[image: Image 1]

[image: Image 2]

In the screenshot u can see first I click on "a" state gets to ["a"] after that when I click on "c" state gets set to "c" but "a" is also highlighted at this point which shouldn't be the case

Comment: do you want user to be able to select multiple options? or one option at a time?

Comment: @sathyareddy one option at a time and thats what happening in the state, but then on the tags the color doesnt reset when other tag is selected

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to have the state logic in the parent component and not in the reusable component unless you make it a list generator component, if you want just one tag at a time no need to store it in an array just use a string. You can figure out rest of the improvements on your own out of this

```
const tagsData = ["1", "2 ", "3"];
const tagsData1 = ["a", "b ", "c"];

export default function FormSection() {
  const [selectedMortgageTag, setSelectedMortgageTag] = useState("");
  const [selectedHolderTag, setSelectedHolderTag] = useState("");

  return (
    <div className="form-section">
      <form>
        <div className="selectable-tags-mortgage">
          {tagsData.map((tag) => (
            <CheckableAntTag
              tag={tag}
              setValue={setSelectedMortgageTag}
              value={selectedMortgageTag}
            />
          ))}
        </div>

        <div className="selectable-tags-holders">
          {tagsData1.map((tag) => (
            <CheckableAntTag
              tag={tag}
              setValue={setSelectedHolderTag}
              value={selectedHolderTag}
            />
          ))}
        </div>
      </form>
    </div>
  );
}

const { CheckableTag } = Tag;

function CheckableAntTag({ tag, value, setValue }) {
  return (
    <CheckableTag
      style={{
        backgroundColor: tag === value ? "red" : "orange"
      }}
      key={tag}
      checked={tag === value}
      onClick={() => setValue(tag)}
    >
      {tag}
    </CheckableTag>
  );
}

CheckableAntTag.propTypes = {
  tag: PropTypes.object,
  value: PropTypes.string,
  setValue: PropTypes.func
};
```

Comment: what if i want to manage multi select option in this, how do i manage state then ?